# reading xls in gdata

Tags: r, xls, gdata

I'm having some 50 xls files that contain monthly data on social benefit recipients. Each file has several sheets but I would like to copy only one sheet from each file, and then paste their columns to a separate file in a sheet next to each other.

I have already installed the gdata package and perl, because I've read in forums that that's a good package to manipulate xls files in R. I have some trouble, however, reading xls files in it, mostly because I’m new to programming. I found a [booklet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/gdata.pdf) which suggest to load xls files with the "read.xls" function and then provides the following usage:

```
read.xls(xls, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, pattern, na.strings=c("NA","#DIV/0!"),
..., method=c("csv","tsv","tab"), perl="perl")
xls2csv(xls, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, ..., perl="perl")
xls2tab(xls, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, ..., perl="perl")
xls2tsv(xls, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, ..., perl="perl")
xls2sep(xls, sheet=1, verbose=FALSE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, ...,
method=c("csv","tsv","tab"), perl="perl")
```

which I find too complicated.

My question is whether gdata is really a good package to manipulate multiple xls files? And if it is, then should I learn the arguments of the read.xls function if I want to do this copy-paste task I described above?

I'm asking this to make sure, I'm on the right track and don’t invest energy into something that will possibly not be useful for me in this task.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: If you only want to read xls files just use a for-loop over `data <- readxl::read_excel(...)` from the readxl package. The rest can be done with R.

Comment: Also, "(...) which I find too complicated." I would highly recommend learning how to use R before using it. Spend a few days purely focusing on learning R, using one of the many resources available online. If you don't do this, you will fall into a trap of spending way too much time on simple things (like for-loops, as suggested by @Christoph), and you'll make a lot of hidden mistakes that you will never notice.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop. `lapply` is the way to go in R. As @Laterow suggested, spend some time learning R.

Comment: @Sumedh To be fair, OP is a beginner, and the `apply`-family is (imho) much harder to understand than a `for`-loop. One step at a time.

Comment: Agreed. I added my comment with an intention to nudge OP in that direction. Even after learning about the `apply` functions, sometimes it is not obvious to use these functions in cases like these

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I've downloaded an intro book to R programming (Zuur et al 2009 A Beginner's guide to R). I will spend a few days with it and then return to the task.